# webpage intro video overlay and how often it plays

Tags: html, video

I am designing a webpage with an overlay intro video. Essentially the moment you enter the webpage an intro video will play. It works and did what I wanted it to do. WHAT I DON'T WANT IT TO DO is play every time I go into this page. What I want to do is:

- Have the video play the moment you enter the page (PAGE A).
- Then lets say you go to page B...
- After that you return to page A and the video doesn't play again until after a certain period of time (lets say 12 hours).

We did figure out a way to do this but we lost the code, so we know its possible.

Anyway you guys can help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

I would look into [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). Either of those can be used to store information in-browser - for example, whether or not the user has seen the video before. On load, check `localStorage` for `videoPlayed` (or whatever you decide to call the variable) and use that to determine whether or not to show the video.

The main difference between the two is that `localStorage` never expires, while `sessionStorage` does once the page/browser is closed.